# Extracting values from comma separated lists

Tags: regex, csv, extract, d

When given a list of comma separated values like `3, asdf, *#, 1212.3`, I would like to extract each of these values, not including the comma, so I would have a value list like `[3, "asdf", "*#", 1212.3]` (not as a textual representation like that, but as an array of 'hits'). How would I do this?

Comment: In what programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you are dealing with CSV files, don't use regex or your own parser. Basically when you think things are simple they really aren't, [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp).

Next up, you say that you would like to have an array ([3, "asdf", "*#", 1212.3]). This looks to be mixing types and can not be done in a static language. And ultimately is very inefficient even using std.variant. For each parsed value you'd have code like:

```
try {
    auto data = to!double(parsedValue);
    auto data2 = to!int(data);
    if(data == data2)
        returnThis = Variant(data2);
    else
        returnThis = Variant(data);
} catch(ConvException ce) { }
```

Now if your data is truely separated by some defined set of characters, and isn't broken into records with new lines, then you can use split(", ") from std.algorithm. Otherwise use a CSV parser. If you don't want to follow the standard wrap the parser so the data is what you desire. In your example you have spaces, which are not to be ignored by the CSV format, so call strip() on the output.

In [the article I linked](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp) it mentions that what commonly happens is that people will write a parser in its simplest form and not handle the more complicated cases. So when you look for a CSV parser you'll find many that just don't cut it. This writing your own parser comes up, which I say is fine just handle all valid CSV files.

Luckily you don't need to write your own as I reciently made a [CSV Parser for D](https://github.com/he-the-great/JPDLibs/tree/csv). Error checking isn't done currently, I don't know the best way to report issues such that parsing can be corrected and continue. Usage examples are found in the unittest blocks. You can parse over a struct too:

```
struct MyData {
    int a;
    string b;
    string c;
    double d
}

foreach(data; csv.csv!MyData(str)) // I think I'll need to change the module/function name
    //...
```

Answer (score 5):

I see you're using the D programming language. Here is a link to a [CSV parser for D](https://github.com/he-the-great/JPDLibs/tree/csv).

Comment: Sorry for not having that much in the way of comments. But the unittest sections should give good examples on how it is used. Also this is probably a better URL: https://github.com/he-the-great/JPDLibs/tree/csv

Comment: @he_the_great: I've updated the link to the new one you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in [perl](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html) you could do something like:

```
@anArray = split(',', "A,B,C,D,E,F,G");
```

Comment: What if some of the CSV fields have commas? eg. `"my,first,field","my,second,field","my,third,field"` which is totally legal in CSV.

Comment: Anyway the OP is using the D programming language. So a perl answer is not relevant.

Comment: @Asaph quite sorry for my suggestion, it seems I made my post just as the clarification regarding the D language had been made. In any event, if commas exist within the field then I would imagine that any CSV parser would have trouble, unless every field was surrounded in quotes, in which case you would need to count quotation marks as you parse.

Comment: @Bnjmn: The rules of CSV parsing are quite simple and parsers are easy to implement. I've done it. Surrounding fields in double quotes is necessary if the field value contains any of the following: a comma, carriage return, newline, or double quote character. Within a quoted string, a double quote character is escaped by another double quote character. If a field value has leading or trailing whitespace, it should be surrounded in double quotes. Surrounding in double quotes is optional at all other times. That's it!

Comment: A comma is illegal input for my purposes (actually it just splits the values in two).

Comment: @Asaph, actually the quotes are not needed for leading/trailing space. Spaces are not ignored even at the beginning and end.

Comment: @he_the_great: The Wikipedia entry on CSV suggests that some parsers out there will strip leading/trailing whitespace. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules The advice to CSV authors is to quote fields that have leading/trailing whitespace so these parsers won't mangle data. When I wrote a CSV serializer (not parser), I made sure to quote fields with leading/trailing whitespace just in case it ever needs to be parsed by one of these nasty parsers. From the parser perspective, it's ok not to require quoting in this case as long as you don't strip whitespace.

Comment: @Asaph, agreed. There hasn't really ever been a standard so implementations can very in many respects. I decided to go with http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Answer (score 0):

`(?:,|\s+)?([^ ,]+)` should do.
It skips a comma or space, then selects anything but a comma or space. Modify to taste.

Comment: This is too simplistic even for the simple CSV format. See comments in  @Bnjmn's for details.